# Rails can't pass/access parameters to controller from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following this [tutorial](https://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/01/05/dealing-with-rails-4-forms-and-params/), and set up what I need to, however I can't seem to get the parameters even though my network headers gets it upon posting.

I'm basically trying to make a downloaded xlsx using axlsx gem. 
In my controller, this line, I need to pass the parameter:

```
@records = Report.get_producer_clients(params[:producer_id])
```

It works well downloading the excel file but I tried printing `@records` at the first row but it doesn't show anything.

Can anyone tell me what I missed?

Here are my code snippets:
**Report.rb (Model)**

```
def self.generate_client(id)
  client = Array.new
  client << get_cinfo(id) << get_caddress(id) << get_cpolicies(id) << get_ccontactinfo(id)
  return client 
end

def self.get_producer_clients(id)
   clients = Array.new
   Request.records(id).each do |client|
     clients << generate_client(client)
   end
  return clients
end
```

**Reports_Controller.rb**

```
def generate_clients
@report = Report.new(report_params)
@id =  params[:producer_id]
@report.queue_status = "Completed"
@report.created_by = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @report.save 
    if @report.report_type == "Producer Clients"
      @records = Report.get_producer_clients(params[:producer_id])
    end

    format.html {
      if @report.batch_generate
        outstrio = StringIO.new
        @report.update_attribute(:date_start, DateTime.now)
        p = render_to_string handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: "reports/create_clients"
        outstrio.write(p)
        @report.update_attribute(:date_end, DateTime.now)
        send_data outstrio.string, filename: "#{DateTime.now.to_date} #{@report.report_name}.xlsx"
      end
    }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report }
  else
    @report.errors.each do |err|
    puts err.full_message
  end
    format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'Both dates must be filled up.' }
    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:from_due_date, :to_due_date, :team_id, :report_type, :report_for, :survey_id, :individual_id, :team_id, :group_id, :user_id, :producer_id, :batch_generate, :queue_status)
end
```

**_clients_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @report , url:generate_clients_reports_path do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs

.form-group.col-md-12
  = f.input :producer_selected, :url => autocomplete_producer_search_string_requests_path, :as => :autocomplete, :wrapper => :field_multi8, :label_html => { :class => "col-md-2 text-right" }, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" }, :id_element => "#report_producer_id", :label => "Producer :", :placeholder => "Find Producer", :update_elements => {}, :autofocus => true
  = f.input_field :producer_id, :as => :hidden
.form-actions
.form-group.col-sm-12{style: "margin-top:20px"}
  .col-sm-9
  .col-sm-2
    = f.submit "Generate", class: "btn btn-new btn-block"
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :reports do
collection do
  post :generate_clients
  get :clients_list
  get :clients_new
end
member do 
  get :download
  patch :on_hold
  patch :activate
  patch :cancel
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `Report.get_producer_clients(params[:producer_id])`, but haven't `params[:producer_id]`. Your form send to controller `params[:report][:producer_id]`. `params` work as Hash and not searching keys inside children's hashes.

P.S. Also, don't give a name to a method with a prefix 'get_'. That is not accepted in the community. You don't need write `return` in the last line in each method, ruby always return that line as a result. Prefer using a method with lengths low 10 lines, other methods rewrite to two or more methods. Try Rubocop or similar gems. So, your model methods can look like:

```
def self.generate_client(id)
  [cinfo(id), caddress(id), cpolicies(id), ccontactinfo(id)] #use Hash instead Array
end

def self.producer_clients(id)
  Request.records(id).each_with_object([]) do |client, clients|
    clients << generate_client(client)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! however I did not understand why I can't access the parameters. According to the tutorial instead of params[:report][:producer], I can call it params[:producer_id] because of `params.require(:report).permit(:from_due_date, :to_due_date, :team_id, :report_type, :report_for, :survey_id, :individual_id, :team_id, :group_id, :user_id, :producer_id, :batch_generate, :queue_status)`

Comment: No, you are wrong. Read more about strong parameters: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters. Also, you call `params[:producer_id]`(not `report_params[:producer_id]`) that is not changed.

Comment: Strong parameters return new value without changing the current. Like: `def report_params;
return params.require...;
end`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, shouldn't you do `Report.get_producer_clients(report_params[:producer_id])` ?

EDIT:
See the documentation about strong parameters:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters